# Count number of points within different ranges SQL

Tags: sql, range, qgis

We have real estate point X.
We want to calculate the number of stations within

```
0-200 m
200-400 m
400-600 m
```

After i have this I will later create a new table where these are summarized according to mathematical expressions.

```
    SELECT loc_dist.id, loc_dist.namn1, grps.grp, count(*)
FROM (
SELECT b.id, b.namn1, ST_Distance_Sphere(b.geom, s.geom) AS dist
FROM stations s, bostader b) AS loc_dist
JOIN (
VALUES (1,200.), (2,400.), (3,600.)
) AS grps(grp, dist) ON loc_dist.dist < grps.dist
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

I have this now, but it takes forever to run and can't get any results since I have more than 2000 entries from both b and s, I want number of s from a specific b. But this calculates for all, how do I add a:

```
WHERE b.id= 114477
```

for example?  I only get syntax error on the join when I try to do this, I only want group distances from one or maybe 5 different b, depending on their b.id

Comment: SELECT loc_dist.id, loc_dist.namn1, grps.grp, count(*)
FROM (
SELECT b.id, b.namn1, ST_Distance_Sphere(b.geom, s.geom) AS dist
FROM stations s, bostader b) AS loc_dist
JOIN (
VALUES (1,200.), (2,400.), (3,600.)
) AS grps(grp, dist) ON loc_dist.dist < grps.dist
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of help from TA, the answer is here and works nicely, added ranges and a BETWEEN clause to get count within the circle rings

```
SELECT loc_dist.id, loc_dist.namn1, grps.grp, count(*)
    FROM (
    SELECT b.id, b.namn1, ST_Distance_Sphere(b.geom, s.geom) AS dist
    FROM stations s, bostader b WHERE b.id=114477) AS loc_dist
    JOIN (
    VALUES (1,0,200), (2,200,400), (3,400,600)
    ) AS grps(grp, dist_l, dist_u) ON loc_dist.dist BETWEEN dist_l AND dist_u
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```